# Splitting a pandas column into two keeping the original column in place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to split into two columns keeping the original column in place.

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'assigned_to': [
{'display_value': 'Michael', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'},
{'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'},
{'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'},
{'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'},
{'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Currently I'm trying to use
`df['assigned_to.display_value'] = df['assigned_to'].str.split(',', expand=True)`

but the `assigned_to.display_value` is coming up with `NaN` as it's population.

My expected results are

```
     assigned_to.display_value    assigned_to.link          assigned_to
0    Michael                      http://www.testlink.com   {'display_value': 'Michael', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'}
1    Vinod                        http://www.testlink.com   {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'} 
2    Vinod                        http://www.testlink.com   {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'}
3    Carrie                       http://www.testlink.com   {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'}
4    Carrie                       http://www.testlink.com   {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://www.testlink.com'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use:

```
df[['Display_value','link']] = df.assigned_to.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
                                         assigned_to Display_value  \
0  {'display_value': 'Michael', 'link': 'http://w...       Michael   
1  {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www...         Vinod   
2  {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www...         Vinod   
3  {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://ww...        Carrie   
4  {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://ww...        Carrie   

                      link  
0  http://www.testlink.com  
1  http://www.testlink.com  
2  http://www.testlink.com  
3  http://www.testlink.com  
4  http://www.testlink.com
```

Or you can use `assign` and create a new dataframe:

```
df_out = df.assign(**df.assigned_to.apply(pd.Series))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                                         assigned_to display_value  \
0  {'display_value': 'Michael', 'link': 'http://w...       Michael   
1  {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www...         Vinod   
2  {'display_value': 'Vinod', 'link': 'http://www...         Vinod   
3  {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://ww...        Carrie   
4  {'display_value': 'Carrie', 'link': 'http://ww...        Carrie   

                      link  
0  http://www.testlink.com  
1  http://www.testlink.com  
2  http://www.testlink.com  
3  http://www.testlink.com  
4  http://www.testlink.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accepting this answer as it seems the simplest. No disrespect to @Coldspeed though, this just works well for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the column to a list of dicts using `tolist`, create a new dataframe by calling the constructor.

```
v = pd.DataFrame(df.assigned_to.tolist())
v

  display_value                     link
0       Michael  http://www.testlink.com
1         Vinod  http://www.testlink.com
2         Vinod  http://www.testlink.com
3        Carrie  http://www.testlink.com
4        Carrie  http://www.testlink.com
```

You can now concatenate the new columns to the original using `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([v, df], 1)

  display_value                     link  \
0       Michael  http://www.testlink.com   
1         Vinod  http://www.testlink.com   
2         Vinod  http://www.testlink.com   
3        Carrie  http://www.testlink.com   
4        Carrie  http://www.testlink.com   

                                         assigned_to  
0  {'link': 'http://www.testlink.com', 'display_v...  
1  {'link': 'http://www.testlink.com', 'display_v...  
2  {'link': 'http://www.testlink.com', 'display_v...  
3  {'link': 'http://www.testlink.com', 'display_v...  
4  {'link': 'http://www.testlink.com', 'display_v...
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
df = df.reset_index(drop=1)
```

```
%%timeit
v = pd.DataFrame(df.assigned_to.tolist())
pd.concat([v, df], 1)

10 loops, best of 3: 58.7 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df.assigned_to.apply(pd.Series)
1 loop, best of 3: 17.5 s per loop
```

Comment: @mnickey carefully evaluate each solution. Dismissing a solution because it “isn’t simple” may not be the best mindset to have. ;) see my answer for a timings comparison, and if you still want to apply a series after, that’s up to you.

Comment: I will do so. Thank you again.